# Not finding a match using fulltext matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, post

I'm using the $.post function to get data

```
var dropbox = $('#dropbox').text();
```

to match up against my query.

```
if(dropbox ){
        $.post("account_main.php", 

          {dropbox: dropbox},
          function(data) {

               $('#demo').html(data);
          });       
        $("#alert_team").show();
        }
```

The data gotten from the post request is only a first name last name and title
and still not matching exactly. Meaning I get other results when I run my query, I'm using FULLTEXT matching see below

```
 $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`WHERE MATCH (firstname, lastname, title) 
            AGAINST ('$dropbox' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 1");
```

What can I do so that the values in firstname, lastname and title pulled from the $.post request match with the columns containing the same values in my database?

Comment: what is format of `$('#dropbox').text();` ? Likely easy to parse it to the column components

Comment: It's text inside a droppable div @charlietfl. Hope that answers your question

Comment: not really ..there is lots of text on this page but none is likely formatted to be able to parse into your query

Comment: why not assign each element to their own variable then pass those to be checked

Comment: Which Storage Engine are you using? FULLTEXT is not supported by InnoDB rather supported by MYISAM only .

Comment: I'm using MYISAM @VardanGupta